# Pine script close trade after certain time

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4, back-testing

if we want to test a strategy that keeps a trade open for a particular time, how do we code that in pinescript?

Eg:

```
strategy(" test ")

long = .....
short = .....

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, 1, when = long)
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, 1, when = short)

strategy.close("Long", when = ?) // ** close long after 5 mins of entry ** //
strategy.close("Short", when = ?) // ** close long after 5 mins of entry ** //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `ta.barssince()`, then convert it to minutes if you want.

```
bars_since_long = ta.barssince(long)

x = 5  // Close after 5 bars

if (bars_since_long > x)
    strategy.close("Long")
```

My code is for v5. Try using `barssince()` without the `ta.` namespace, if needed.